# how can we make world of warcraft 2.4.3 packet in c# without using wow path

Tags: game-engine

> hello i have a wow server Arcemu on local Ip and I want check accounts
>   if they exist on wow server with c# by sending packets for example i
>   want to send a udp pack with c# it includes username , password , ...
>   and server return succed (999 status ) how can I do that?

Comment: can someone make wow socket with c#?

Answer (score 0):

**here is my code :**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
public class clnt {

    public static void Main() {


        try {
            TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");

            tcpclnt.Connect("serverip", port);


            Console.WriteLine("Connected");


 String username= "username";
 String password= "password";
bool HasPassword;
int[] Selected;
       bool AutoUpdate ;
         bool Minimize;
           bool Hide ;




            HasPassword = false;
            Selected = new int[] { 0 };
            AutoUpdate = true;
            Minimize = true;
            Hide = false;

            Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

            ASCIIEncoding asen= new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] user=asen.GetBytes(username);
            byte[] pass= asen.GetBytes(password);


            Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

            stm.Write(user,0,user.Length);
            stm.Write(pass, 0, pass.Length);
            byte[] bb=new byte[1400];
            int k=stm.Read(bb,0,1400);

            for (int i=0;i<k;i++)
                Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));

            tcpclnt.GetStream();


            NetworkStream clientStream = tcpclnt.GetStream();
            StreamReader clientStreamReader = new StreamReader(clientStream);
            Console.WriteLine(clientStreamReader.Read().ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

}
```